# total word and character counts across multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently the following code tracks word and character counts for a textarea with the id `text`.

However, I'd like it to tally the results of multiple text areas. How can I achieve this?

```js
counter = function() {
  var value = $('#text').val();
  if (value.length == 0) {
    $('#wordCount').html(0);
    $('#totalChars').html(0);
    $('#charCount').html(0);
    $('#charCountNoSpace').html(0);
    return;
  }
  var regex = /\s+/gi;
  var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
  var totalChars = value.length;
  var charCount = value.trim().length;
  var charCountNoSpace = value.replace(regex, '').length;
  $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
  $('#totalChars').html(totalChars);
  $('#charCount').html(charCount);
  $('#charCountNoSpace').html(charCountNoSpace);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#count').click(counter);
  $('#text').change(counter);
  $('#text').keydown(counter);
  $('#text').keypress(counter);
  $('#text').keyup(counter);
  $('#text').blur(counter);
  $('#text').focus(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  Words: <span id="wordCount">0</span><br/> Total Characters (including trails): <span id="totalChars">0</span><br/> Characters (excluding trails): <span id="charCount">0</span><br/> Characters (excluding all spaces): <span id="charCountNoSpace">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want separate totals for each textarea, or a singe set of totals that totals across multiple textareas?

Comment: Just loop through all the textareas and write ur logic inside that: $("textarea").each(function() { ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change ID to class, so that you can attach your plugin to multiple elements. Converted your code to function as a plugin. Try the below:

```js
counter = function() {
  if ($(this).next('div.result').length) {
    $(this).next('div.result').remove();
  }
  var output = '<div class="result">Words: <span class="wordCount">0</span><br/> Total Characters (including trails): <span class="totalChars">0</span><br/> Characters (excluding trails): <span class="charCount">0</span><br/> Characters (excluding all spaces): <span class="charCountNoSpace">0</span></div>';

  $(this).after(output);
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length == 0) {
    $(this).next('div.result').find('.wordCount').html(0);
    $(this).next('div.result').find('.totalChars').html(0);
    $(this).next('div.result').find('.charCount').html(0);
    $(this).next('div.result').find('.charCountNoSpace').html(0);
    return;
  }
  var regex = /\s+/gi;
  var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
  var totalChars = value.length;
  var charCount = value.trim().length;
  var charCountNoSpace = value.replace(regex, '').length;
  $(this).next('div.result').find('.wordCount').html(wordCount);
  $(this).next('div.result').find('.totalChars').html(totalChars);
  $(this).next('div.result').find('.charCount').html(charCount);
  $(this).next('div.result').find('.charCountNoSpace').html(charCountNoSpace);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#count').click(counter);
  $('.string-example,.regex-example').on('change keyup focusout blur', counter);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Highlight Within Textarea</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Droid+Sans+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- highlight-within-textarea CSS/JS -->
  <link href="https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.js"></script>

  <!-- custom styles for highlight-within-textarea -->
  <style>
    .hwt-container {
      background-color: #f8f9fa;
    }
    
    .hwt-content {
      width: 760px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #adb5bd;
      color: inherit;
      font: 18px/25px 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .hwt-input:focus {
      outline-color: #495057;
    }
    
    .hwt-content mark {
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #d0bfff;
    }
    
    .hwt-content mark.red {
      background-color: #ffc9c9;
    }
    
    .hwt-content mark.blue {
      background-color: #a3daff;
    }
    
    .hwt-content mark.yellow {
      background-color: #ffec99;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- general styles to make this page look decent -->
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 40px auto;
      padding: 0 20px;
      font: 18px/1.4 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: #495057;
      background-color: #f1f3f5;
    }
    
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #f8f9fa;
      background-color: #495057;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    section {
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
    code {
      padding: 0 5px;
      font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #dee2e6;
    }
    
    script {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      border-left: 5px solid #adb5bd;
      background-color: #e9ecef;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      font: 14px/1.5 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Highlight Within Textarea</h1>
  <p>Some demos and code snippets for using the plugin. Edit textareas to see the real-time highlighting. View page source to see the CSS.</p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea/tree/master">Go to GitHub repo</a>
    <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlight-within-textarea">Go to npm package</a>
  </p>

  <section>
    <h2>String</h2>
    <p>Note that this is case-insensitive.</p>
    <textarea class="string-example">Potato potato tomato potato.</textarea>
    <script>
      $('.string-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: 'potato'
      });
    </script>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>RegExp</h2>
    <p>Don't forget the <code>g</code> (find all) and <code>i</code> (case-insensitive) flags if you need them.</p>
    <textarea class="regex-example">Dog, cat, chicken, goose. Dogs, cats, chickens, geese.</textarea>
    <script>
      $('.regex-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: /dogs?|cats?|g(oo|ee)se/gi
      });
    </script>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Array of Two Numbers (Range)</h2>
    <p>An array of exactly two numbers is treated as a range. Highlighting starts at the first character index (inclusive) and ends at the second character index (exclusive).</p>
    <textarea class="range-example">abcdefgh</textarea>
    <script>
      $('.range-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: [2, 6]
      });
    </script>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Array of Other Things</h2>
    <p>You can highlight multiple things, using any types mentioned here, with an array.</p>
    <textarea class="array-example">apple watermelon banana orange mango</textarea>
    <script>
      $('.array-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: [
          'orange',
          /ba(na)*/gi, [0, 5]
        ]
      });
    </script>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Function</h2>
    <p>You can use a function for custom logic. It can return any of the types mentioned here. Return anything falsey (<code>false</code>, <code>undefined</code>, etc.) to indicate no highlighting. The current textarea input is provided to it for convenience.</p>
    <textarea class="function-example">Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat :) &lt;-- remove the smiley...</textarea>
    <script>
      function getSmileyDayString(input) {
        const dayStrings = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
        if (input.indexOf(':)') !== -1) {
          let dayIndex = (new Date()).getDay();
          return dayStrings[dayIndex];
        } else {
          // no smiley, no highlighting
          return false;
        }
      }

      $('.function-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: getSmileyDayString
      });
    </script>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Custom Object (with Class Name)</h2>
    <p>Any type mentioned here can be put in an object wrapper with <code>highlight</code> and <code>className</code> properties. This lets you set CSS classes in the highlight markup for custom styling, such as changing the highlight color.</p>
    <textarea class="class-example">Here's a blueberry. There's a strawberry. Surprise, it's a banananana!</textarea>
    <script>
      $('.class-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
        highlight: [{
            highlight: 'strawberry',
            className: 'red'
          },
          {
            highlight: 'blueberry',
            className: 'blue'
          },
          {
            highlight: /ba(na)*/gi,
            className: 'yellow'
          }
        ]
      });
    </script>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually using http://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/ which is being knocked out of sync when the results are appended. Any thoughts on how to get round this?

Comment: Thanks, it's coming up with a similar issue - if you enter a few paragraphs, in your example, and then add the word `potato` to see the highlighting, it will display in the wrong place.

Comment: Hmm, that's a plugin problem. Can't fix it asap. It's a separate issue and should be tackled separately. You can up-vote and mark this question as done, if this satisfied your original needs and have a new question for this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways:

1. Giving the text as a class name for all the text area.
2. Using $(textarea) in the each loop like this:

Following will give the `id` for the text area where you can get the values.

```
$(textarea).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).id);
});
```